# Table view with image caching and "pull to update" option

Tags: ios, uitableview, three20

Almost every ios app now has something like "Feed" option.
Programming that usually includes fetching images from the web, caching them, handling pages, "pull to update option", etc. - all the standart stuff.

But looks like there is no standart solution for that?

- I tried "three 20" - really big, complicated library with many modules. It really lacks good documentation! And it also had "slowdowns" while fetching images from cache.
- Maybe I should use different small libraries for each small task separately? Like HJCache, EGO, etc.
- Or is it better to write everything from scratch without any libraries?

Please give me advice on best practices here, i am really stuck now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This one](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) is very easy to drop in for pull to refresh.

For image loading, I wrote the following category for UIImageView:

```
// .h
@interface UIImageView (UIImageView_Load)
- (void)loadFrom:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(UIImage *))completion;
@end

// .m
#import "UIImageView+Load.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIImageView (UIImageView_Load)

- (void)loadFrom:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(UIImage *))completion {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (data) {
            self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            if (completion) completion(self.image);
        }
    }];
}

@end

// To use it when building a cell

//...

MyModelObject *myModelObject = [self.myModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (myModelObject.image) {
    cell.imageView.image = myModelObject.image;
} else {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:myModelObject.imageUrl];
    [cell.imageView loadFrom:url completion:^(UIImage *image) {
        // cache it in the model
        myModelObject.image = image;
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    }];
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @danh! Unfortunately it doesn't include any caching solution. But I will give leah's "pull to refresh" a try.

Comment: @Danik - sure. That code I pasted in does a lazy load and caches within the model on the callback.

Comment: Yes, I see now, you cache it in myModelObject.image! Do you clear cache on didReceiveMemoryWarning or restrict it's maximum size?

Comment: I drop the whole model - and therefore the cached images - on memory warning.  I do not restrict size, though it's a reasonable extension to provide an image getter in the model that also records the time, and a "cleanup" that disposes of non-recent images.  I do advocate keeping the images with the model, so they are "just there" when other views access the model.  (no need to pass around a cache, too).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Leah Culver's [Pull to Refresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) library, or this [STableViewController](https://github.com/shiki/STableViewController) which handles pull-to-refresh as well as endless scrolling downward.

For image loading, try [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) from the DailyMotion app.

Comment: Thanks! I also use Leah's Pull to Refresh and SDWebImage for my current project.