# The right approach to loading dynamic content into a UITableView in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

ok, I've read tons of bits and pieces on the subject of loading dynamic content (from the web) into a UITableView and the problem with calculating cell height upfront. I've tried different simple implementations but the problem persists...

Assuming I need to read a JSON file from the web, parse it into 'item' objects, each with variable size image and various text labels, **here is what I believe would be the right approach to avoid long hang time of the app while everything is loading**:

1. on app load read JSON file and parse into items array
2. provide only small part of the items array to the tableview (about 10 items) - since I need to load the images associated with each item to calculate cell height - I don't want the view to go through the whole items list and load all images - this hangs the app until every image is loaded
3. display the tableview with the available cells (assuming I load a few 'spare' ones, user can even scroll to more items)
4. in the background using Grand Central Dispatch download images for all/some of the remaining items and then reload the tableview with the new data (repeat step 4 if item list is very long)

Step 2 above is necessary since I have no way to calculate the cell height without loading the images first, and since tableview first calculates height of all cells it may take a very long time to download all images for all items.

Would you say this is the right approach? am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you standardize in the tableview the image size.  Then you can manipulate the images as they are displayed to fit the size.  Offer a way to view the image if selected.  The Quartzcore framework will allow you to take your original images and size them.

I only suggest this because it would make your tableview look more appealing with uniform picture sizes than with random ones.

Comment: Agreed. Take the Flickr approach and crop them to a uniform square size.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the show must go on, even while your data is still loading.  So you'll want to design a cell that looks attractive before it has the correct image.  A common approach is to ship a default image and format the cell so that looks good.

To handle the height, the tableView datasource protocol can ask you how tall a cell should be.  The way to answer is, in pseudo code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  id myModelElement = [self.myModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  UIImage *image = myModelElement.image;
  if (!image) image = self.placeholderImage;

  return kFIXED_HEIGHT + image.size.height;
}
```

You're also correct that you'll want to load the images asynchronously.  [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896347/table-view-with-image-caching-and-pull-to-update-option/9896753#9896753) for a very simple approach to that.   No GCD, not even a table row reload.

Comment: Danh, if I calculate cell height in heightFor... Then I must first load all images... That's what's I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Right, you might not have images loaded yet, but you still need a row height.  This is why I suggest a placeholder - an image shipped in your app bundle that looks pretty until a real one arrives.